# Many2one res.partner Filter in CRM module

Tags: xml, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I am trying to apply a group by on customers in the opportunities section of the CRM module.

I want to group the customers/opportunities on `industry`.

I have used similar code in `res.partner` and I cannot work this one out!.

*models.py*

```
x_industry_id = fields.Many2one(string="Industry", comodel_name="res.partner")
```

*views.xml*

```
 <record id="view_crm_case_opportunities_filter_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">crm.lead.search.opportunity</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.view_crm_case_opportunities_filter"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

     <xpath expr="//search" position="inside">

        <filter name="x_industry_id" string="Industry" context="{'group_by':'x_industry_id'}" domain="[('industry_id','!=', False)]"/>

       </xpath>

    </field>
</record>
```

I am also having the same issue with filters and other groups using the same method.

They just do not appear like normal!

How can I apply Groups and Filters to different models

Comment: have you had time to check if the answer solves your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `domain` parameter and put your filter inside the `group` tag of the `search` tag, since you are trying to create a *group*, not a *domain filter*:

```
<record id="view_crm_case_opportunities_filter_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">crm.lead.search.opportunity</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.view_crm_case_opportunities_filter"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//search/group" position="inside">
            <filter name="x_industry_id" string="Industry" context="{'group_by':'x_industry_id'}"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

In `search` views there are three kind of filters:

- **Filter by text**: allow users to compare a field to some text and find those records which match the expression. They use the `field` tag and parameters like `filter_domain` or `operator`, among others (E.g.: `<field name="lost_reason"/>`).
- **Filter by domain**: allow users to click on the filter you have created and see only the records which match the domain you have specified. They use the `filter` tag and the `domain` parameter, among others (E.g.: `<filter string="My Pipeline" name="assigned_to_me" domain="[('user_id', '=', uid)]" help="Opportunities that are assigned to me"/>`).
- **Filter by group**: allow users to group records by a field. They are inside the `group` tag in a search view, use the `filter` tag and the `context` parameter (with the key `group_by`), among others (E.g.: `<filter string="Salesperson" context="{'group_by':'user_id'}"/>`).

So I think you are mixing two kinds of filters. That is why you should remove `domain`.

And of course, check that you have added the `crm` dependency in the `__manifest__.py` file, and restarted Odoo service (updating your module) after this.